# Nth term of series with distinct difference

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am learning some series as a naive and I came across this series where I want to find the nth term.

2, 6, 14, 30, 62, ... and so on.

I am facing difficulties as the difference between elements is formed as

4, 8, 16, 32,....

Is it possible to find nth term for this series?

Comment: Don't you recognize this sequence - 4, 8, 16, 32? These are powers of 2.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, I do recognize that but the problem is I am not able to form a nth term by original sequence I have posted above.

Comment: Obviously, $2^n-2$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: Assuming that the sequence starts at $n=2$. But hopefully the OP can figure out how to perform the shift if that's not the case.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, thanks for the comment. I think I was missing the basic behind the series. I guess your suggestion is what I was looking for. And at the same time,  I will try understanding the answers by other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$U_2-U_1=2^2$$

$$U_3-U_2=2^3$$

$$U_4-U_3=2^4$$

So by proceeding in this manner we get that, $$U_n-U_{n-1}=2^n$$

Now by adding these equations we get

$U_n-U_1= 2^2+2^3+2^4+.....+2^{n-1}+2^n \Rightarrow U_n=U_1+2^2+2^3+2^4+.....+2^{n-1}+2^n$

$U_n=2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+.....+2^{n-1}+2^n$

Therefore $$U_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k$$

$$U_n=\frac{2^{n+1}-2}{2-1}$$

$$U_n=2^{n+1}-2$$

Comment: You can simplify that further, as Ivan Neretin's comment indicates.

Answer (score 0):

The first one has a logic as n+1=  2 n+2 example 6=2.2+2 14= 6.2+2 an the next one is geometric series having a common ratio 2 the nth term of this series is given by a.r^(n-1). Here a is first term so a=4 and r is the common ratio which is 2. thus nth term of 1 st sequence is n+1=2n+2 and 2nd is a.r^(n-1)